# Converter array JavaScript em um Objeto JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6, objetos

O array **JavaScript** abaixo é o resultado de uma consulta **MySQL**:

> json-database.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server CPU",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server Hard Disk",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server RAM",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server CPU",
        "node_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server Hard Disk",
        "node_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server RAM",
        "node_id": 2
    }
]
```

> Consulta MySQL:

```
SELECT N.id, N.name AS node_name, C.id AS children_id, C.name AS children_name, C.node_id
FROM tab_nodes AS N
INNER JOIN tab_nodes_children AS C
ON N.id = C.node_id
```

> Preciso converter o array em um objeto JavaScript com a estrutura
>   abaixo:

```
nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product',
      children: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server CPU'
        }, 
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server Hard Disk'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server CPU'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product',
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server CPU'
        }, 
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server Hard Disk'
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'Virtual Private Server CPU'
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
```

Estou tentando utilizar o **reduce** com **Object.assign**, mas está dando erro.

Comment: Você não pode fazer isso, já que o seu array contém diversos objetos com a mesma assinatura, o que criaria um problema de colisão de propriedades. Qual é a sua motivação para querer fazer algo assim?

Comment: Eu coloquei valores repetidos nesse teste, mas na realidade os valores serão diferentes.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando angular v7 que, em um dos componentes, terá uma visualização em árvore. Para isso estou usando o seguinte pacote:https://angular2-tree.readme.io/
Para montar a estrutura desejada eu preciso seguir o padrão recomendado por eles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal seria que a sua tentativa fosse postada para encontrarmos o que está errado, mas a lógica é bastante básica, apenas crie um novo array com o formato desejada. Se um nodo com o id já existe no array, apenas faça um `push` no `children`, se não existe, adicione o nodo.

```js
const dados = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server CPU",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server Hard Disk",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server RAM",
        "node_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server CPU",
        "node_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server Hard Disk",
        "node_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "node_name": "SP2 - Virtual Private Serve Product",
        "children_name": "Virtual Private Server RAM",
        "node_id": 2
    }
];

const dadosFormatado = dados.reduce((acc, d, i) => {
    const nodo = acc.find(a => a.id === d.id);

    if (nodo) nodo.children.push({
        id: i + 1,
        name: d.children_name
    });
 
    else acc.push({
        id: d.id,
        name: d.node_name,
        children: [{
            id: i + 1, 
            name: d.children_name
        }]
    });
 
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(dadosFormatado);
```